# stacked bar plot in r with percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

i browsed the internet and documentation for some time now and cannot come up with a solution. I am new to R so that is certainly part of the problem...

I want to create a bar plot with ggplot, which stacks the individual shares on top of each other. There exists only one variable which has 5 values but see for yourself: 
The data looks like this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "type share   
               A 10
               B 30
               C 40
               D 20", header = TRUE)
```

The only thing i arrive at, is that the shares are displayed next to each other.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=type, y=share )) +   geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

What i want to have is one "pillar".

Hope someone can help.

Cheers

Comment: `ggplot(dat, aes(x="", y=share, fill=type)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Comment: thanks a lot. This solves it!